# Function in SSRS to remove prefix from Addresses

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am attempting to remove the prefixes from addresses in SSRS. An example would be 123 Main St. I would only want the report to read Main St. Also, another example would be 123 1st St. i would only want the report to read 1st St.

Is there a function in SSRS to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple expression.

```
=Mid(Fields!addr.Value, InStr(Fields!addr.Value, " ") + 1)
```

To break this down, we use the `InStr()` function to find the first instance of a `space`.

Taking `123 Main St.` as an example, the first space is at position 4

We then use the result of this +1 (as we want to start getting text from the next character position) in the `Mid()` function.

The `Mid()` function reads "Take a portion of the string in `Fields!addr.Value` starting from position 5 (in this case). As we don't specific the length parameter to the `Mid()` function, the entire remainder of the string is returned.

This gives us `Main St.`

In this simple table I have a column showing the position of the first space for illustration, followed by the result.

[image]

Obviously you need to swap out the field name for the field that contains your address.

Comment: Be careful as this would fail if you have an address that doesn't start with a number. The assumption is that all addresses is not strictly true. One example I am aware of is Carmel, California: https://ci.carmel.ca.us/post/addresses

Another example are PO Boxes.

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln This method does not rely on the address containing a number, only that it contains a space. It would fail is there was no space and a check should be added for this.

Comment: Imagine "PO Box 123". The function you provided will return "Box 123". This would be a failure as it trims non-numeric values.

Comment: That is not what the question asked so your comment, even if it has some validity in general, has no relevance to this question which specifically stated by example that the first part of the address needs to be removed.

Comment: His examples clearly show he is trying to remove street numbers even if his terminology was incorrect. Just trying to save the guy a surprise problem when he comes across an address where this method doesn't give him his expected results.

Comment: The answer answers the question. If you want to add an answer go ahead, I'm not proud.